# Can auto evaluate in Debug console in VCode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

With PyCharm it is possible to select a piece of code and evaluate directly, without the need to click. That is, just select the piece of code and press the key combination to display the debugger with the variable included and its value. Is it possible to do this in VSCode? I see that if I click ctrl+may+Y open the debuger console, but the variable is not setted.

Comment: Its not completely clear what you mean. You can use start REPL to get a terminal where you type python code and it is immediately executed. If you have a jupiter notebook installed you can also do this in  the python-interactive window. In that case shift-enter should do it.

Comment: I will try to explain myself better.
I would like that when debugging, if I point to a piece of code I could press some key combination to include it in the debug console. The "Evaluate in Debug Console" option does not accept a key combination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to:
`File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`

Search for
`Evaluate in Debug Console`
double click on it.

I tested it for example with `Ctrl+Insert`

Worked as of August 2020, tested on a Ubuntu 18.04 system

Answer (score 0):

add to setting.json

"lldb.consoleMode": "evaluate",